# Plesk reports that updates were not installed for the following items

Tags: php, wordpress, wptoolkit

I received this message yesterday on email from Plesk and there are a lot of items listed.
It appears to be to do largely with Wordpress Toolkit on the server. Plesk is the interface I use on my Ionos Hosted Server.

Sites are working from the server ok but obviously updates will not happen whilst these errors are present.
Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this and how to fix it please.

Thanks

1. Website "eeeSafe Community Safety Sustainability and Skills" (https://eeesafe.com): PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php:418
   Stack trace:
   #0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(418): date()
   #1 [internal function]: Cron_Event_Command::format_event()
   #2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(460): array_map()
   #3 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(366): Cron_Event_Command::get_cron_events()
   #4 [internal function]: Cron_Event_Command->delete()
   #5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/CommandFactory.php(100): call_user_func()
   #6 [internal function]: WP_CLI\Dispatcher\CommandFactory::WP_CLI\Dispatcher{closure}()
   #7 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/Subcommand.php(491): call_user_func()
   #8 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(419): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\Subcommand->invoke()
   #9 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php(1443): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command()
   #10 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/plesk/wp-cli-toolkit-command/src/Wpt_Cron_Command.php(30): WP_CLI::run_command()
   #11 [internal function]: Wpt_Cron_Command->reschedule()
   #12 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/CommandFactory.php(100): call_user_func()
   #13 [internal function]: WP_CLI\Dispatcher\CommandFactory::WP_CLI\Dispatcher{closure}()
   #14 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/Subcommand.php(491): call_user_func()
   #15 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(419): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\Subcommand->invoke()
   #16 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(442): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command()
   #17 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1276): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command_and_exit()
   #18 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
   #19 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
   #20 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
   #21 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php(17): require_once('...')
   #22 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/wpt-wp-cli.php(31): require_once('...')
   #23 {main}
   thrown in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php on line 418
   Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php:418
   Stack trace:
   #0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(418): date()
   #1 [internal function]: Cron_Event_Command::format_event()
   #2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(460): array_map()
   #3 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php(366): Cron_Event_Command::get_cron_events()
   #4 [internal function]: Cron_Event_Command->delete()
   #5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/CommandFactory.php(100): call_user_func()
   #6 [internal function]: WP_CLI\Dispatcher\CommandFactory::WP_CLI\Dispatcher{closure}()
   #7 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/Subcommand.php(491): call_user_func()
   #8 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(419): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\Subcommand->invoke()
   #9 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php(1443): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command()
   #10 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/plesk/wp-cli-toolkit-command/src/Wpt_Cron_Command.php(30): WP_CLI::run_command()
   #11 [internal function]: Wpt_Cron_Command->reschedule()
   #12 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/CommandFactory.php(100): call_user_func()
   #13 [internal function]: WP_CLI\Dispatcher\CommandFactory::WP_CLI\Dispatcher{closure}()
   #14 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Dispatcher/Subcommand.php(491): call_user_func()
   #15 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(419): WP_CLI\Dispatcher\Subcommand->invoke()
   #16 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(442): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command()
   #17 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1276): WP_CLI\Runner->run_command_and_exit()
   #18 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
   #19 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
   #20 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(32): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
   #21 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php(17): require_once('...')
   #22 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/wpt-wp-cli.php(31): require_once('...')
   #23 {main}
   thrown in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/cron-command/src/Cron_Event_Command.php on line 418
   Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.

I thought it might be something to do with enablin mysqli on my server, where Plesk Web Pro is being used.
I can't find how to do that, but not convinced yet that this might be the answer.

Comment: `I thought it might be something to do with enablin mysqli `...why? None of the errors mention mysqli.

Comment: That was something someone else said could be the reason, when I did some online research. So it was what I wanted to try, but no help on enabling it on the server.